# Can't change appearance on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, themes

Trying to change GTK Theme, Icon Theme or Wallpaper and results in nothing. When I try to remove things from the launcher, they come back...

Already tryed to remove *"./compiz"*, *"./config"* and *".profile"* from */home/"my_user"* but the problem persists.
I'm using Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.7, and my home is encrypted (actually, I'm receiving a error message about encryption during boot time).

I'll truly appreciate some help, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, works after renaming `~/.config` to `~/.config.bak` and restarting the machine.

Comment: Hi -- could you explain what you renamed `/.config` from or to? I'm having a similar problem to yours.

Comment: Sorry for the delay im my response. I was meaning the "./config" in the /home directory

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the owner of the file `user` to my user from root
file is can be found in the following path 
`/home/.config/dconf/user`

This fixed my problem.